# Showing $|f(x)| > \frac{1}{2} |f(p)|$ if f continous and $f(p)$ not $0$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, triangle-inequality

Suppose $f$ is a "nice" function. Show that if $f$ is continuous and with $f(p)\neq 0$ , then for some $\delta$ neighbourhood of $p$ we have: $$|f(x)| > \frac{1}{2} |f(p)|$$

I can obtain $f(x) > \frac{1}{2} f(p)$ quite easily from the triangle inequality but unsure of how to get the inequality with modulus included.

EDIT: Just realised something, we have: 
$$|f(x) - f(p) | \rightarrow 0$$
But in particular this implies 
$$|~~ |f(x)| - |f(p)| ~~| \rightarrow 0$$
And then the desired inequality drops out by setting $\epsilon = \frac{ |f(p)|}{2}$. Thank you for the help in the commenets :)

Comment: The triangle inequality holds precisely with the modulus ;)

Comment: Consider the function $g(x)=|f(x)|-\frac{1}{2}|f(p)|$, which is continuous and positive in $p$. Then you can find a neighbourhood of $p$ in which $g$ is positive.

Comment: qwertyguy. Why not write a short answer ?

Comment: You can also consider the triangle inequality in the form $\left||a|-|b|\right|\leq |a-b|$. Then, $\left||f(x)|-|f(p)|\right|\leq |f(x)-f(p)|$.